# Using phprc to change php.ini values

Tags: php

Hi i'm currently using phprc txt file (dir is home/username/.php/5.3/) to alter a couple of the php.ini values to:

```
allow_call_time_pass_reference = ON
session.use_only_cookies = 0
```

These changes aren't being reflected on the site. Is it possible that they are being looked over? I also looked to change the .ini file it's self and it isn't in the root dir neither is the /etc.

Comment: What has lead you to believe that the location you've specified is actually paid any attention to by PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your directory path, I'm going to assume you're on Dreamhost or have seen instructions for Dreamhost users? If you are on Dreamhost trying to use this, the file needs to be `phprc`, no extensions.

Answer (score 0):

After phprc creation you need to restart apache.
But on dreamhost you can't so the only way to get this working is submitting a ticket.